# Show link preview. I want my link to contain image, title description etc

Tags: html, web

Currently when I send my website link it doesn't show anything.

I want it to show a preview of my website like so (on Discord):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VCXn.png

What exactly should I add? Perhaps a metatag??
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears Stack Overflow accomplishes it with the following `meta` tags:

```html
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://stackoverflow.com/">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Stack Overflow">
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded">
<meta name="description" content="Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share​ ​their programming ​knowledge, and build their careers.">
```

The `og:` symbolizes the tags are part of the [Open Graph](https://ogp.me/) protocol

Comment: thank you, but it appears that it doesnt update a bit... i'm using cloudflare and I purged everything is there any delay??? I'm on a ovh machine btw.

Comment: @weasley I might be cached. Have you tried clearing your cache on Discord?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the `meta` tag with `description` attribute is the one responsible for such SEO information related to search results on search engines.

Add this in your `<head></head>` tag

```
<meta name="description" content="A description of the page" />
```

**Edit:**

For more customization on the search result preview (*Adding an image*) those meta tags can be used

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/ogp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/ogp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="A shiny red apple with a bite taken out" />
```

Note that the issue might be happening due to used protocol `HTTP` or `HTTPS` without using the appropriate `meta` tag.

For more information about the **Open Graph Protocol** visit
[this link](https://ogp.me/#structured)

Hope this helped.

Comment: and what about the image?

Comment: use property="og:image" content="image URL"